# My Tuition teacher doesn't let me pray Salah. Who will be sinned and what should I do?

Tags: salat, sin

Assalam o Alaikum,
This story is of my friend. He is in Class 10. And his paper are near. So he is at his Tuition center for around 6 to 7 hours. In this time period, There are two Salahs, Asr and Magrib. But the problem is that his Tuition teacher doesn't let him go to the mosque or let him pray at home. And If my Friend doesn't obey him. He beats him up. My friend told me that his Sir never prays Salah expect Jumma or Eid. And nowadays, He doesn't let him go. Sometimes my friend lies to his Sir so he can go and pray and in that condition his sir lets him go. But he cannot Lie everyday. So what should he do so that he can go and pray in time? And will the teacher be sinned for all the Salah's my friend leave because it is not under control of my friend. And if my friend doesn't obey. He beats him up a lot.

Comment: Your friend should inform his parents and they should talk with the teacher or even change him. A person in 10th grade is usually aged 15-16 at which age one can be considered an adult, so Islamically your friend is considered responsible and independent. He has to pray and can disobey anyone who prevents that. Anyone who stops him is also obviously committing a sin.

Answer (score 1):

Both will be sinful. The one who is missing the prayer and the one who is preventing it. It is important for you to arrange your daily activities around the prayer times and keep away from schools and teachers that do not allow you to do that, so as to protect his religious commitment, because prayer is the foundation of Islam and anything that distracts from doing it is not permissible. Allah says in Surah Kahf verse 28

> **Keep yourself patiently with those who call on their Lord** (i.e. your
> companions who remember their Lord with glorification, praising in
> prayers, and other righteous deeds) morning and afternoon, seeking His
> Face; and let not your eyes overlook them, desiring the pomp and
> glitter of the life of the world; and **obey not him whose heart We
> have made heedless** of Our Remembrance, and who follows his own
> lusts, and whose affair (deeds) has been lost.